# gmail api authentication not working (javascript)

Tags: javascript, gmail-api, google-api-js-client

Authentication is failing for the following code and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

First the relevant html `script`:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

Now the javascript:

```
var clientId = "xxxxxxxx";
var apiKey = "xxxxxxxx";
var scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send";

function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
}
function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: clientId,
        scope: scopes,
        immediate: true
    }, handleAuthResult);
}
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        loadGmailApi();
        console.log("gmail authentication passed");
    } else {
        console.log("gmail authentication failed");
    }
}
function loadGmailApi() {
    gapi.client.load("gmail", "v1", close);
}
function close() {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you followed this documentation about [Authentication using the Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication).

All requests to the Gmail API must be authorized by an authenticated user. Gmail uses the [OAuth 2.0 protocol](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) for authenticating a Google account and authorizing access to user data. You can also use [Google+ Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in) to provide a "sign-in with Google" authentication method for your app.

Also, here's the [JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js) which might help.

```
// Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';    
      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

/**
 *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
 */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for too long, I finally decided to pursue an approach using php on the server side using the email server packaged with my web hosting provider. So while I can't answer why this isn't working, I can recommend to send emails using the server side.